Sending Data from Python Code on Github to Wix Website
Simplified I have the following procedure going on. A user puts in data on Wix, which is send using a webhook (smee.io) to my python code, located in my Github repository. The data is used for some calculations and some parameters are obtained.
All of this works perfectly fine.
However, now the data should be sent back to Wix, expecting a POST request. And that's where things start breaking down.
The data is sent but not fetched by WIX.
So, I tried debugging the procedure in a virtual environment.
Following my Python code at the end showing the data to be send as well as the (modified, thus fictional) site_id, WIX API token and wix-account-id.
# Data to be send and send back to Wix to the dedicated site
            results = {
            "SelfSufficiency": float(self_sufficiency),
            "BatteryType": battery_type,
            "BatteryCost": int(battery_cost),
            "PaybackTime": float(payback_time)
            }

            headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer IST.eyJ....", # My WIX API token
            "wix-account-id": "12c....",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
    
            # Sending data to the specific site on WIX website
            site_id = "6b2cd5aa-...." 
            wix_url = f"https://www.wixapis.com/site-list/v2/sites/{site_id}/query"
    
            # Log the payload and headers before sending
            logging.debug(f"Sending payload to Wix: {results}")
            logging.debug(f"With headers: {headers}")
    
            response = requests.post(wix_url, headers=headers, json=results)

However, I obtained the following error:
DEBUG:root:Sending payload to Wix: {'SelfSufficiency': 74.13495121509517, 'BatteryType': 'sonnenBattery10p/11', 'BatteryCost': 26000, 'PaybackTime': 9.3}
DEBUG:root:With headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer IST.eyJr...', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wixapis.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.wixapis.com:443 "POST /site-list/v2/sites/e6e64d9d-b3ff-4e.../query HTTP/11" 302 293
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): users.wix.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://users.wix.com:443 "GET /signin?originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&redirectTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&overrideLocale=en HTTP/11" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): users.editorx.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://users.editorx.com:443 "GET /auth/getssomagiclink?originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&redirectTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&overrideLocale=en HTTP/11" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://users.wix.com:443 "GET /signin?originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&redirectTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wixapis.com%2Fsite-list%2Fv2%2Fsites%2Fe6e64d9d-b3ff-4e5d-b842-d0dd5c045698%2Fquery&overrideLocale=en&forceRender=true HTTP/11" 400 None
ERROR:root:Failed to send data to Wix:

angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('staticsUrl', '//static.parastorage.com/services/wix-public/1.719.0/');
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('baseDomain', 'wix.com');
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('language', 'en');
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('errorCode', {code: '400'});
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('data', {});
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('exceptionName', '');
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('serverErrorCode', '-15008');
angular.module('wixErrorPagesApp').constant('requestId', '1722231783.87325224461548821016');

INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - \[29/Jul/2024 07:23:53\] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR:root:Error in webhook processing: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - \[29/Jul/2024 23:47:08\] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I am a bit of a newby, so maybe getting feedback on where to improve the code or if its just a real simple simple mistake would be very great.
Thank you for the responses!

It looks like this is your error: ERROR:root:Error in webhook processing: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'. So you're passing something to your float() function that's not set.
